# Connecting to another mysql database and update database tables when other database is update

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to connecting a remote mysql server and auto update another database in the same time? 
For example my database:

```
Database one: user id  user name  pass
```

When adding or updating user in database two, user name in database one updates.
How can I do this if possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Connect how? Auto update how? Using what client - can you use PHP or must this happen inside mySQL?

Comment: With using php. I want to insert user information from another database to my database dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automating this inside mySQL may be possible using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) but that is complex and requires mySQL 5.

Wouldn't it be an option to do the logic in PHP? Adding a query to update database B whenever database A is updated?

Comment: Im looking for this php query. (may be simple, but im confusing about this issue). Thanks alot

Comment: @TheNone it's just a normal database query, isn't it? Hard to tell what it needs to look like without knowing anything about the table structure and code